# A back slash get added before the json string and throws issue with deserialization

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have returned JSON data from the API call which when read as string from the HTTP response adds a backslash before the flower braces ({) in the start and end of the JSON string. Due to this while deserializing the JSON value to an object throws an exception.

I have read the string using the below code.

```
string value = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And the result is

"\"{\"key\":null}\""**

Due to unwanted slashes added before after this curly braces, throws an exception in deserialization as JSON value could not be converted to the object type.

Comment: It is escape characters

Comment: So it looks like the slashes are just how Visual Studio displays the string to you. It also looks like the HTTP call is giving you a JSON encoded string, it's hard to tell exactly.

Comment: If it is in your variable, you can do `value.Replace("\\", "");`

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: @RufusL this is the exception The JSON value could not be converted to (my custom object).

Comment: Can you post the **actual** JSON that is returned by the HTTP call? Do a `Console.WriteLine` for example and give us that output.

Comment: The slashes are escape characters for the double quotes inside the string, which is used for display purposes only; they are not actually characters in the string itself. The string you've shown above actually looks like `"{"key":null}"`. You can remove the outer quotes using the `Trim` method by doing: `value = value.Trim("\"");`

Answer (score 2):

It seems the API you are requesting for the key response serializes the object to `JSON` twice or so. It usually gives the escaped string like you mentioned.

Try this:

```
var unescaped = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(value);
var key = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyKeyClass>(unescaped);
```

Assuming your MyKeyClass is something like this:

```
public class MyKeyClass {
   public string Key { get; set; }
}
```